# How to validate an ASP password login form?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have an ADO.Net login form as my frontend, and I want to check if the username and password input from the user matches the correct values in the database. How can I accomplish this as easily as possible?

By the way, my user information table in the database is called Login.

Comment: WTF? C#4? Not even close, try 'homework' tag.

Answer (score 3):

1. Do not store plain text password in the database. **Never.**
2. The ASP.NET Login form has an OnLogin or something similar event. You need to attach a method to it.
3. Query the database for the credentials of the user that tried to log in. That is:

SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE USERNAME = @P_USERNAME;

Then you compare the password you got from the database with the password the user entered, and you're done.

Comment: To clarify the apparent conflict between points one and three, you use a function like SQL Server's HashBytes() to store a HASH of the password, rather than the password itself.  When the user tries to login, you also hash the credential they entered, and then compare the hashed values.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) instead. Than use the login control.

Bruno Figueiredo

Answer (score 0):

For the least lines of code, use forms authentication and the asp login control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178331.aspx